# Connection pooling in a sample blog project

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to design a practice blog application using Bottle in Python and i am current designing a class which connects to the database and runs the queries passed to it.

The class code so far looks like this(Not finished yet):

```
import configparser
from os.path import dirname,abspath

class ExecuteQuery():
    def __init__(self,query):
        self.query = query
        d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
        self.config = d + "\config\Config.conf"
    def getconndetails(self):
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(self.config)
        configitems = config.items("MYSQL")
        hostname = configitems["hostname"]
        user = configitems["user"]
        password = configitems["password"]
        return (hostname,user,password)
    def execute(self,query):
        (hostname,user,password) = self.getconndetails()
```

Now since the rest of the code in the application would be using this same class to run any query against the database i was thinking should i instantiate a connection pool to make the connection ?

Also can someone guide me as to how should i check if the connection pool object has already been created and i can use that ?

This is the first time i am designing something like this so if someone can guide me with the code for this i will be grateful. I am using MYSQL as the backend database.